# Android SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document

Tags: android, xml

I get this exception while parsing XML, but not always. After error When I try again immediately, it works. But why I get sometomes this error ? 
Here is my code and error too.

```
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(author, "UTF-8");        
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        SharedPreferences logIn = context.getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(logIn.getString("Url", ""));
        httppost.setEntity(entity);  
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");               
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);                           
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
        xmlRecords  = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
            NodeList workItemsNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("Items");
         for (int i = 0; i < workItemsNode.getLength(); i++) {

                 //Some Code here

             }
```

**Exception**

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
>         at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:125)
>         at com.mobile.syrinx.services.SynchroniseWorkItemsService.FillLists(SynchroniseWorkItemsService.java:101)
>         at com.mobile.syrinx.services.SynchroniseWorkItemsService.doInBackground(SynchroniseWorkItemsService.java:65)
>         at com.mobile.syrinx.services.SynchroniseWorkItemsService.doInBackground(SynchroniseWorkItemsService.java:1)
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)

Answer (score 2):

1)  Verify that you're receiving valid XML.  If you're consuming XML provided to you from a webservice, well who knows what you're getting.  Invalid XML can cause problems for a lot of these parsers.  The fac that this only occurs sometimes makes me think that is most likely the culprit.

The DocumentBuilder documentation is here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)

You can see that the SAX exception is thrown when there is an error parsing the xml, this implies that the xml is invalid somehow.  The exception should be caught and handled acordingly.

2)  Are the files you are parsing originating on different OS's than the one you're acting on?  This has caused problems for me in the past, where a windows file caused errors to parsers on linux systems.  This *shouldn't* be the problem here I don't think, but it is possible.